# Remove a set of nonconsecutive characters (as a String) from another String?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to generate s3 string by removing from s1 all characters appearing in s2.

For example :

```
String s1 = "Computer"; 
String s2 = "mur";
```

Result must be : `"Copte"`

I tried to do: `s3 = s1.replace(s2, "");` but it does not work. I get the same word: `computer`.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4975978/remove-specific-characters-from-string-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s1.replace(s2, "")` works when `s2` is substring of `s1`. However, `mur` is not a substring of `Computer`. Since `m` `u` `r` are substrings of `Computer`, you can remove them separatly.

```
String s1="Computer", s2="mur";
for (char c : s2.toCharArray()) {  // create a char array [m, u, r]
    s1 = s1.replace(String.valueOf(c), "");  // remove them separatly
}
System.out.print(s1);
```

Comment: Thank you. But one thing, this part (char c : s2.toCharArray()) ... What does this syntax mean ? where the variable c comes from ? (Sorry, I am new in Java).

Comment: @OlegKhegay `mur` is not a `substring` of `Computer`. `s2.toCharArray()` will split `s2` to single character, then you can use these character to construct new strings which contains only one character,  these strings are `substring` of `s2`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use replaceAll witch accept regex :

```
String result = s1.replaceAll(String.format("[%s]", s2), "");// Output Copte
```

---

If your string contain some special characters, for example `} { ) ( . -` this character can be part from the regex syntax, in this case you have to escape them, you can just use `Pattern.quote(s2)` like this :

```
String result = s1.replaceAll(String.format("[%s]", Pattern.quote(s2)), "");
```